# Rails Simple Form Required Field Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a simple form, I have made the name field required, however, I am still able to submit this form without providing a name. The HTML validations are not kicking in.

```
<%= simple_form_for @company do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, required: true %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Is there something wrong with the simple form syntax here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What worked for me was to enter the simpleform initializer configuration i.e `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` and then change `config.browser_validations` to true.

I think it's turned off by default for some reason